# Is it possible to plot a multi column histogram side-by-side in Matlab using histogram() instead of hist()

Tags: matlab, histogram

Using the `hist()` function it is possible to plot this: [image: [link](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/examples/graphics/CreateHistogramBarPlotwithMatrixInputExample_01.png).]

Matlab recommends using `histogram()` instead of `hist()`.

Plotting multiple histograms in the same plot using `histogram()` leads to this: [image: [link](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/examples/matlab/PlotMultipleHistogramsExample_01.png)]

The columns overlap each other and are not side-by-side.

Is it possible to plot a histogram with the columns side-by-side *within the same plot* using the `histogram()` function? If yes, how do I do it?

Code snippet:

```
a = randn(100, 2);

edges = -3:3;
xbins = edges(1:end-1)+0.5;

figure(1)
hist(a, xbins)

figure(2), hold on
histogram(a(:, 1), edges)
histogram(a(:, 2), edges)
```

Comment: Post some dummy code for both methods (i.e. so we can see the structure of your data)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

[Click here for a picture of the resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GAtp.png)

```
data1 = randn(1000,1);
data2 = randn(1000,1);
data2 = data2 - 1.5*ones(size(data2));

lowest_boundary = min(min(data1), min(data2));
highest_boundary = max(max(data1), max(data2));
nbins = 10;

boundaries = linspace(lowest_boundary, highest_boundary, nbins + 1);

bin_assighnments1 = discretize(data1, boundaries);
bin_assighnments2 = discretize(data2, boundaries);

bin_counts1 = zeros(numel(boundaries) - 1, 1);
bin_counts2 = zeros(numel(boundaries) - 1, 1);

for m = 1:numel(bin_assighnments1)
    n = bin_assighnments1(m);
    bin_counts1(n) = 1 + bin_counts1(n);

    n = bin_assighnments2(m);
    bin_counts2(n) = 1 + bin_counts2(n);
end

merged_bin_counts = cat(2, bin_counts1, bin_counts2);

x = zeros(1, nbins);

for m = 1:nbins
    x(m) = (boundaries(m) + boundaries(m+1))/2;
end

bar(x, merged_bin_counts);
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

[histograms in two separate subplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdHUB.png)

```
x1 = randn(100,1);
x2 = randn(100,1);

figure_rows = 1;
figure_cols = 2;

figure
subplot(figure_rows, figure_cols, 1);
histogram(x1);
title('Hist One')

subplot(figure_rows, figure_cols, 2);
histogram(x2);
title('Hist Two')
```

Comment: To make the plotted results easy to see I tried to embed the image in my answer, but apparently I need at least 10 reputation points before stackoverflow will let me do that.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I want the bars to be side-by-side within the same plot to more easily compare values.

Comment: Please edit your answer to be correct rather than posting ANOTHER answer on the same post.

Comment: Suever asked me to edit my answer to be correct rather than posting a second, new, "corrected," answer on the same post. I do not consider one answer to be correct and the other to be incorrect. Both of my answers are correct. The way the original question was asked was ambiguous to allow both of my different answers to be potentially useful.